# make bigger space for legend in echarts

Tags: echarts

I'm using echarts

this is my chart[image: echarts]

this picture shows I lost some of my legends , so,how do I make bigger space for legends, is it possible to set more space for legends? or if it is possible to make my chart smaller how can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I put

```
var option = {
    grid: {
        y: 30,
        y2: 90,
    },
```

y mean space before chart, y2 - after chart

Comment: can you explain whats going on Thanks

Comment: for echarts you use code   `var myChart = ec.init(document.getElementById('main'));`  `myChart.setOption(option);` to create chart.  You should add 'grid:' in var 'option' to manage space after chart